# What is GCP Organization?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I want to create an OAuth Application for my development purposes. But I am stuck in the problem. I do not know how to create this Application for my organization (for internal use only). Where can I find my organization or how can I create my organization and place there my projects (with internal scope).
As you understand I want to skip submitting my app for a review. How could it be properly done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCP Organization resource is the root node of the GCP (Google Cloud Platform) resource hierarchy and all resources that belong to an organization are located under the organization node. An Organization resource is automatically created when user associated with a G Suite domain creates a project or billing account. Each G Suite account is associated with exactly one Organization. Also Organization is associated with exactly one domain, which is set when the Organization resource is created. So you don't need to create organization by yourself if you're a G Suite customer because Organization resource has been provided to you automatically.
Please refer to [this article](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization) for more information about Managing Organization and getting info about it.

As for creation of G Suite application for internal usage only it's quite simple. You just need to create regular project as described [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/preparing) and setup G Suite Marketplace SDK API. The most important thing before publishing you application to Marketplace is that you should set Visibility option value to "My Domain" (application will be only available to users at inside your domain) as described [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/sdk#completing_the_configuration_panel). Please note that this option can't be changed after saving the configuration. If you set Visibility option value to "My Domain" for you G Suite application verification process is skipped by Google while publishing this application and you can easily use it for testing purpose inside and only inside you domain.